# Passing user input values from a JOptionPane dialog box in Main to other classes in package

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I am rather new to java programming, so I am probably making hundreds of mistakes, especially in the way I am using classes and organization of my program.

What I would like to do is use a JOptionPane to obtain a few integer and double inputs from the user (with the defaults in the boxes when the optionpane appears.

Currently I have a Main class with my main method and the JOptionPane code in the main class. I would like to pass some of the input values to a public final class, where I have many static values used by a couple of other classes in my program.

My Optionpane code looks as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    JTextField simsInput = new JTextField("1");
    JTextField pphInput = new JTextField("0");

    Object[] inputs = {
        "Number of simulations",simsInput,
        "Input people per household (0 for random pph based on probability",pphInput
    };

    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, inputs, "User Inputs", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    String simsInputString = simsInput.getText();
    int numSimsI = Integer.parseInt(simsInputString);
    String pphInputString = pphInput.getText();
    int pphI = Integer.parseInt(pphInputString);
```

Can I, say for instance pass pphI to a public final class, to be used by other classes as a constant through the execution of the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that a class is `final` just means that it can't be extended (through the keywork `extends`), which does not seem to be a problem in your case.

However, if you want pphI to be treated as constant by other classes, there could be various approaches. For example:

**The static way**: Create a static field in your class, to store the constant:

```
public static int pphI;
```

and assign it right after your read user inputs:

```
pphI = Integer.parseInt(pphInputString);
```

Then other classes can access it with:

```
YourClass.pphI;
```

Note that this approach would be a bit unsafe because other classes could modify pphI at will. So as an alternative, you could make the field private, and create a *static* getter:

```
private static int pphI;
public static int getPphI(){ // Now the field is Read-Only from other classes
  return pphI; 
}
```

Now other class access the field with:

```
YourClass.getPphI();
```

**The non-static way:** Pass the variable to instances of the other classes you will create from your `main` method.

```
SomeOtherClass object = new SomeOtherClass(pphI);
```

And in the constructor of SomeOtherClass, you would have something like:

```
class SomeOtherClass {

  private final int pphI;

  public SomeOtherClass(int pphI){ // Constructor
     this.pphI = pphI;
  }

  public void someMethod(){
    System.out.println(pphI); // Print the constant
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem was that I tried to use public and static modifiers within the "public static void main(String[] args){" method, which was not allowed. I moved my code out of this method and created a new void method getInputs(), which gets called in the main method and then assigns the input values to private variables in the class. Which I created getters for.